# Accessing the last few log entries of Log4Net

Tags: c#, log4net

In my application logging goes through Log4Net. I have a specific appender that for various reasons I can only register with Log4Net later in the application lifetime. However there can be entries logged before this appender is getting registered and I'd like all such entries to be logged through this appender as well.

Is there any way to make Log4Net "replay" the entries since the app start? Is there any internal in-memory buffer that contains the last n log entries that I could use?

There are other appenders registered suitably early in the application (I can't touch how these work and I can't add any other appender) that could possibly help. There is a RollingFileAppender and DebugAppender. Because of this the only suitable solution I could come up with would be to parse the log file.

Is there any better way?

Comment: I see you said you can add any other appender. You can make a new custom appender - it would register the log events as long as you want.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to write that I _can't_ add new appenders (corrected). So basically the earliest I can do anything in the app is when I also register my own appender. Now I need to get the log entries that were made before that.